# Programming Language Source Lexer

Tags: rust, lexical-analysis, compiler

I have a lexer (program that turns source code into tokens) written in Go that I am re-writing in Rust.

The lexer should take in a sequence of tokens, generally different special characters, integers, or string sequences (identifiers) and output tokens representing those 'types'.

I'd like to write more idiomatic Rust, using non-mutable data wherever possible, but the current 'design' is akin to OOP with a struct mutating itself in most methods. I am struggling to come up with a better design that is more idiomatic Rust, so input would be highly appreciated.

As you can see in the code below, the `Lexer` struct holds different position counters that are mutated in most methods, meaning that the entire struct is passed as mutable. This seems to be a specific code smell to me, and I would like to refactor that out if nothing else.

```rust
use crate::token::{match_keyword, Token};

/// A lexer contains a vector of characters as well as various pointers to read and peek characters
/// in the input.
pub struct Lexer {
    input: Vec<char>,
    position: usize,      // current reading position
    peek_position: usize, // current peeking position
    ch: char,             // current char under examination
}

impl Lexer {
    pub fn new(input: String) -> Self {
        let in_vec: Vec<char> = input.chars().collect();
        let c = in_vec[0];
        Self {
            input: in_vec,
            position: 0,
            peek_position: 1,
            ch: c,
        }
    }

    pub fn next_token(&mut self) -> Option<Token> {
        self.skip_whitespace();

        let tok = match self.ch {
            '+' => Token::PLUS,
            '-' => Token::MINUS,
            '*' => Token::ASTERISK,
            '!' => {
                if self.peek_char()? == '=' {
                    self.read_char(); // advance past '='
                    Token::NEQ
                } else {
                    Token::BANG
                }
            }
            '?' => Token::QUESTION,
            '>' => Token::GT,
            '<' => Token::LT,
            ',' => Token::COMMA,
            ';' => Token::SEMICOLON,
            '(' => Token::LPAREN,
            ')' => Token::RPAREN,
            '{' => Token::LBRACE,
            '}' => Token::RBRACE,
            '|' => {
                if self.peek_char()? == '>' {
                    self.read_char();
                    Token::PIPE
                } else if self.peek_char()? == '|' {
                    self.read_char();
                    Token::LOR
                } else {
                    // FIXME is there a way around this?
                    Token::ILLEGAL(String::from(self.ch))
                }
            }
            '/' => {
                // TODO add comment support aka skip anything from double // to newline
                if self.peek_char()? == '/' {
                    // need to skip to newline
                    while self.ch != '\n' {
                        self.read_char();
                    }
                    Token::COMMENT // this will be discarded in parsing. maybe keep it for reflection
                } else {
                    Token::SLASH
                }
            }
            '"' => {
                while self.peek_char()? != '"' {
                    self.peek_position += 1;
                }
                self.position = self.peek_position; // catch current pos up to the peek
                Token::STRING(
                    self.input[self.position..self.peek_position]
                        .into_iter()
                        .collect(),
                )
            }

            _ => {
                if self.ch.is_alphabetic() {
                    let mut lit = String::from(self.read_char());
                    while self.input.get(self.position)?.is_alphabetic() {
                        lit.push(self.read_char());
                    }
                    match_keyword(lit.as_str())
                } else if self.ch.is_digit(10) {
                    let mut lit = String::from(self.read_char());
                    while self.input.get(self.position)?.is_digit(10) {
                        lit.push(self.read_char());
                    }
                    Token::INT(lit.parse::<i32>().unwrap()) // FIXME better error handling
                } else {
                    Token::ILLEGAL(self.ch.to_string())
                }
            }
        };
        self.read_char();
        Some(tok)
    }

    fn read_char(&mut self) -> char {
        self.ch = *self.input.get(self.position).unwrap_or(&'\0'); // FIXME
        self.position += 1;
        self.ch
    }

    fn peek_char(&self) -> Option<char> {
        // if self.peek_position >= self.input.len() {
        //     '\0'
        // } else {
        //     self.input[l.readPosition]
        // }
        if let Some(ch) = self.input.get(self.peek_position) {
            Some(*ch)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    fn skip_whitespace(&mut self) {
        while self.ch == ' ' || self.ch == '\t' || self.ch == '\n' || self.ch == '\r' {
            self.read_char();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you interested in keeping track of the position? Typically, lexers are able to indicate _where_ the token started (a byte offset at least, line/column being more expensive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a high-level, I would say there are two potential roads for improvement in this code:

1. The side-effect methods. You noted yourself that struct is passed mutably; that's not a problem, really, since a lexer will keep track of state. The real issue is that some methods are invoked *only* for their side-effect of changing the state, not returning anything.
2. Performance wise, that's a *lot* of memory allocations.

#### Performance: memory allocations

Your code doesn't, for the most part, require to allocate anything, so all those allocations are superfluous.

This can be handled by borrowing, instead:

```rust
struct Lexer<'a> {
    content: &'a str,
    iterable: Peekable<Chars<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    pub fn new(content: &'a str) -> Self {
        let iterable = content.chars().peekable();

        Self { content, iterable }
    }
}
```

And we can change the tokens to match:

```rust
enum Token<'a> {
    String(Cow<'a, str>), // Allocation may be necessary with escape characters.
    ...
}
```

Note that I also eliminated the manual cursors here:

- `content` now points to the *not-yet-parsed* slice.
- `iterable` points to the *not-yet-parsed* char view of the slice.

There's thus no need to keep a "current" index, and we should aim at eliminating the "peek" index.

#### Mutation: eliminate side-effects

One of the issues you are facing is the side-effect only `read_char` method, which is a bit awkward.

Instead, what we can have is a method that combines moving the cursor, and returning what was covered for use. Or two, one by index -- efficient -- and one by predicate -- for flexible needs.

```rust
impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    //  Advances by n chars, and returns a reference to the characters skipped.
    fn advance_by(&mut self, n: usize) -> &'a str {
        let n: usize = self.iterable
            .take(n)
            .map(|c| c.len_utf8())
            .sum();

        let (head, tail) = self.content.split_at(n);
        self.content = tail;

        head
    }

    //  Advances as long as the predicate returns true, and returns a reference
    //  to the characters skipped.
    fn advance_while<F>(&mut self, predicate: F) -> &'a str
    where
        F: FnMut(char) -> bool,
    {
        let n: usize = self.iterable
            .take_while(predicate)
            .map(|c| c.len_utf8())
            .sum();

        let (head, tail) = self.content.split_at(n);
        self.content = tail;

        head
    }
}
```

*Note: if you wish to keep track of the position, which I'd encourage you to track as byte offset, you'd augment the `advance_xxx` methods to return both strings and starting position.*

I'll also split the `next_token` method. The checks will look a bit redundant, but your `next_token` is just too damn big -- and prone to get bigger as you handle escape sequences, etc...

```rust
    /// Returns the next Token, or None if no such Token exist.
    pub fn next_token(&mut self) -> Option<Token<'a>> {
        self.skip_whitespace();

        let next = self.iterable.peek()?; // short-circuit execution if `None`.

        match next {
            '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' => self.next_arithmetic(),
            '<' | '>' | '=' | '!' => self.next_comparator(),
            '(' | ')' | '[' | ']' | '{' | '}' => self.next_bracket(),
            '.' | ',' | ';' | '?' => self.next_punctuation(),
            '"' | '\'' => self.next_string(),
            '0'..='9' => self.next_digit(),
            'a'..='z' | 'A'..='Z' => self.next_identifier_or_keyword(),
            _ => todo!("Handle weird characters..."),
        }
    }

    fn skip_whitespace(&mut self) {
        self.advance_while(|c| c.is_whitespace());
    }
```

All the "simple" methods can advance by 1 character only.

```rust
impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    fn next_arithmetic(&mut self) -> Option<Token<'a>> {
        let next = self.advance_by(1)[0];

        match next {
           b'+' => Some(Token::Plus),
           b'-' => Some(Token::Dash),
           b'*' => Some(Token::Star),
           b'/' => Some(Token::Slash),
           _ => unreachable!(),
       }
    }
}
```

Comparisons are trickier, involving either 1 or 2 characters:

```rust
impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    fn next_comparison(&mut self) -> Option<Token<'a>> {
        let current = self.advance_by(1)[0];
        let next = self.advance_while(|c| c == '=');

        match (current, next) {
            ('<', "") => Some(Token::LessThan),
            ('<', "=") => Some(Token::LessThanOrEqual),
            ('>', "") => Some(Token::GreaterThan),
            ('>', "=") => Some(Token::GreaterThanOrEqual),
            ('=', "") => Some(Token::Assign),
            ('=', "=") => Some(Token::Equal),
            ('!', "") => Some(Token::Bang),
            ('!', "=") => Some(Token::Different),
            (_, _) => todo!("Handle lexing errors gracefully"),
        }
    }
}
```

For strings, it gets a bit more complicated but that's encapsulated:

````rust
impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    fn next_string(&mut self) -> Option<Token<'a>> {
        let content = self.content;

        let open = self.advance_by(1)[0];

        let n = self.advance_while(|c| c != open).len();

        let close = self.advance_by(1).get(0).expect("Lexer errors to be handled");

        Some(Token::String(Cow::Borrowed(&content[(n + 2)..])))
    }
}
```
````

Comment: I wonder if all the lifetimes there are needed, as reading code with them can be really hard, if you know barely anything about rust. I do like how you made everything a lot more readable overall anyway.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Lifetimes on `impl` blocks themselves cannot be elided, and eliding the lifetime on `-> Option<Token<'_>>` would tie the lifetime of `Token` to that of `&mut self` (ie, the Lexer's lifetime) which would not work. So I am afraid they are needed if performance is a goal. As you get more used to Rust, you'll soon skip over them :)

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. I do need to read a little more of rust. Also, on the `(_, _) => todo!([...])`, wouldn't it make sense to keep using `Token::ILLEGAL(self.ch.to_string())` (or some variation) to handle the errors?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: As a starter, yes indeed. I missed it. You should use `&'a str` to reference the issue, and I would suggest adding some "error-code", to denote the nature of the issue. If your lexer matures, you may want to switch to a separate system to track errors -- allowing you to include more details without bloating the `Token` enum.

Answer (score 7):

## Disclaimer

I've **NEVER** written Rust, used Rust anywhere, or done anything with/about Rust.

However, I do have to say that, what you have there, is extremely easy to read and understand, even for a [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) like myself.

---

---

### `next_token()`

This function has a bad bug: It doesn't handle escape sequences.
In fact, it makes it impossible to have strings with double-quotes inside, which is bad!

This is the relevant code:

```rust
while self.peek_char()? != '"' {
    self.peek_position += 1;
}
self.position = self.peek_position; // catch current pos up to the peek
Token::STRING(
    self.input[self.position..self.peek_position]
        .into_iter()
        .collect(),
)
```

In this block, you could do something like this instead:

```rust
let mut stop = false;
while !stop {
    let cur_char = self.peek_char()?;
    
    if(cur_char == '"') {
        stop = true;
    } else if(cur_char == '\\') {
        self.peek_position += 2;
    } else {
        self.peek_position += 1;
    }
}
```

The idea is to jump 2 positions when you find a backwards slash (`\`).
You can do proper validation to allow other escape sequences, and to validate the current escape sequence.

As I'm not a Rust developer, I have no idea if this works, but the idea is to show the intent, not a working code.

---

### Still in `next_token()`

You have this piece here:

```rust
Token::COMMENT // this will be discarded in parsing. maybe keep it for reflection
```

I can tell you, with confidence, that you should keep comments, even in the parser.

If you transpile/compile this code into another language, having this comment there could actually be very useful, if you intend to make the output human-readable.

---

### More `next_token()`...

You have the following code to handle the asterisk:

```rust
'*' => Token::ASTERISK,
```

This code doesn't handle the power syntax (`**`).

If the tokenizer you're using doesn't have a way to handle the power syntax, you will have to find a way to handle it somehow - I can't find the crate you're using.

---

### `peek_char()`

Please avoid keeping comments with useless stuff in them.
For example:

```rust
// if self.peek_position >= self.input.len() {
//     '\0'
// } else {
//     self.input[l.readPosition]
// }
```

These comments provide no value at all for the *existing* code, and should be removed.

---

### `skip_whitespace()`

This function is kinda unnecessary, but I understand why it is separated.

But, it can be better written anyway.

Instead of doing this:

```rust
while self.ch == ' ' || self.ch == '\t' || self.ch == '\n' || self.ch == '\r' {
    self.read_char();
}
```

You can use the [`char::is_ascii_whitespace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_ascii_whitespace) method instead:

```rust
while self.ch.is_ascii_whitespace()
{
    self.read_char();
}
```

However, it doesn't consider *all* UTF-8 white-space.
For example, a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;` in HTML) is a white-space.

You may want to use the [`char::is_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_whitespace) method instead, to handle those:

```rust
while self.ch.is_whitespace()
{
    self.read_char();
}
```

Comment: For someone who has never written Rust, you've made spot-on comments on the use of built-in std methods that even Rust developers regularly skip! Kudos!

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thank you. I did take time to check up on this, before I wrote my review. I always check this type of stuff when reviewing any code I know nothing about. There's no need to re-invent the wheel for this type of basic stuff if this is already (better) implemented by someone/something else.